# Compare dates in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I would like to check if a campaign is currently active or not. The dates `deal.Campaign.start` and `deal.Campaign.end` are strings from my backend, `now` is a date object. How can I cast the strings to date objects in the HTML file?

Ideally I would create the date objects in the controller, but this does not work as I loop over the objects in the HTML file.

controller.js:

```
$scope.now = new Date();
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-repeat="deal in deals"> 
    <span ng-show="deal.Campaign.start < now && deal.Campaign.end > now">
        <span>Active</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would resolve this is turn all `Date`s into ms strings:

`$scope.now = new Date().getTime();`

And same with your other dates:

`$scope.deal.Campaign.start = Date.parse($scope.deal.Campaign.start);`

This way you would be simply comparing numbers.

Considering `ng-repeat`, this is still doable, though through a function:

```
$scope.formDate = function(date) {
  return new Date(date).getTime();
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<span ng-show="formDate(deal.Campaign.start) < now && formDate(deal.campaign.end) > now">
```

Comment: I am looping over `deals` in the HTML file. How can I do this there?

Comment: Ah, missed the `ng-repeat`. Updating answer (though it might be a little less pretty)

Comment: Can you guarantee that *Date.parse* will correctly parse the format provided, especially since "*…strings from my backend*" could be anything and *Date.parse* is almost entirely implementation dependent?

Comment: I'm uncertain of the significance of that question. If a standard date is stored in a standard format in the backend (like miliseconds from Linux epoch), shouldn't all major browser implementations of `Date` recognize this? If not, then you could write your own date parsing function, I suppose.